# How to deal: QSqlQuery::exec() returns false

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite, qt, qt5

I'm using Qt and sqlite3. The problem is:

QSqlQuery::exec() returns false.

I thought it is caused by QSqlDatabase::open() because it always returns true!
I found that actually does not matter what i set using QSqlDatabase::setDatabaseName(), it will return true, because sqlite will create non existing DB.

I used QFile::exist to test if DB exists. But everything is fine and QFile sees the db.

Code:

```
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    db.setDatabaseName("temp_client_db.sl3");

    QFile datebase("temp_client_db.sl3");

    if (!datebase.exists() || !db.open())
    {
       QMessageBox::critical(this, "Error", "Database isn't connected.");
    }
    else
    {
        QSqlQuery query;
        query.prepare("SELECT * FROM exist_ask");

        if (!query.exec())
        {
             QMessageBox::critical(this, "Error", "\"SELECT exist_ask\" works badly.");
        }
        else
        {
             ...
```

[image: messagebox]

Comment: what is the output of `qDebug() << query.lastError().toString();` inside `if (!query.exec())`

Comment: It is likely that the table does not exist or there is a misspelling.  Try iteration through result of `QSqlDatabase::tables()` to confirm it exists, or use a separate DB manager application to inspect database.

Comment: @eyllanesc Thanks for help. I found the problem. Somehow, even QFile reported that I have a file, but in fact, I just did not add the database to the build directory.

Comment: @CPerkins Thanks for help. I found the problem. Somehow, even QFile reported that I have a file, but in fact, I just did not add the database to the build directory.

Comment: @VolodimirPavlenko sqlite has a particular characteristic: If the database does not exist then sqlite will create it. If you want to verify that the database exists then you must do it before opening the database.

Comment: @eyllanesc Oh, i think it should be true. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did not add the database to the build directory.